# Regular Expression to insert a dash before the final character?

Tags: regex

Totally new at this and no search has been able to help me.

Trying to turn:

Jan104aca

Into:

Jan104ac-a

/(?<=.)(?!$)

Gets me to every space, just not sure how to isolate the final space

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
(.*)(.)
```

and substitute it for:

```
\1-\2
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/Detzpn/1)

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    (.)$
Replace: -$1
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead pattern to assert that a match is followed by a character and the end of the line/string:

Search for:

```
(?=.$)
```

Replace with:

```
-
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/LfK29V/1

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, but you have to assert a character followed by the end of the string.

In the replacement use `-`

```
(?<=.)(?=.$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I85n9e/1).

Or match the single character and only use the lookahead. Then use the full match followed by `-` in the replacement.

```
.(?=.$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l2Uhpp/1)